# Returning Expression<> using various class properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have something like this:

```
public Expression<Func<Message, bool>> FilterData()
{
    switch (this.operatorEnum)
    {
        case FilterParameterOperatorEnum.EqualTo:
            return message => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Body) &&
                              message.Body
                                     .Equals(this.value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        case FilterParameterOperatorEnum.NotEqualTo:

            return message => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Body) &&
                              !message.Body
                                     .Equals(this.value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        case FilterParameterOperatorEnum.Contains:

            return message =>
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Body) &&
                    message.Body.IndexOf(this.value,
                                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;

        case FilterParameterOperatorEnum.DoesNotContain:
            return message =>
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Body) &&
                    message.Body.IndexOf(this.value,
                                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1;


    }
}
```

As you can see this is done on `Message.Body`

I now what to do the same thing on other string properties on the `Message` class and I don't want to duplicate all that code.

Is there a way to do that by passing in the property somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try composing the expression completely manually, which will give you the ability to specify the property name as a string. This isn't a complete solution and it's untested, but it may give you a starting point to see what I mean:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Message), "o");
var getname = Expression.Property(parameter, "Body");

var isnullorempty = Expression.Not(Expression.Call(typeof(string), "IsNullOrEmpty", null, getname));
var compare = Expression.Equal(getname, Expression.Constant("thisvalue"));

var combined = Expression.And(isnullorempty, compare);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda(combined, parameter);
```

So you would change your function to accept "Body" as a parameter, and then cast the lambda at the end to:

```
expression<func<Message, bool>>
```

I may not have got the syntax for creating the lambda exactly right though.

Answer (score 3):

Eclude the expression that retrieves the property value into a separate lambda expression:

```
public Expression<Func<Message, bool>> FilterData(Func<Message, string> retrievePropValueFunc)
```

In your filter expressions, you can then call that new lambda expression (just showing one as an example):

```
return message => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(retrievePropValueFunc(message))
        && retrievePropValueFunc(message)
                .Equals(this.value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

To get to the `Body` property, pass `message => message.Body` to the `retrievePropValueFunc` parameter; as you see, you can modify this to pass different lambda expressions for the retrieval of other properties just as well.

Comment: Does the `retrievePropValueFunc` need to be an `Expression<Func<...>>` as well?

Comment: I currently get "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: @SteveGreatrex how do you call retrievePropValueFunc if its an expression

Comment: @Jon I think that error message is *because* it uses a function instead of an expression.  I'm not certain, but you might be able to call the expression as if it were a function

Comment: using the above code `retrievePropValueFunc(message)` it wont compile

Comment: @SteveGreatrex: Indeed, it is  the cause of your error. I think you'll have to build a <code>MemberExpression</code> by hand somehow, which will take the name of the property as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your function to receive the property instead of the message.

Or the hard way pass one more parameter for the property name and select it using reflection.

Edit just for one option than change for all the options.

```
    public Func<Message, string, bool> FilterData()
    {
        return (message, propName) =>
        {
            var prop = message.GetType().GetProperty(propName);

            if(prop != null){
                var propValue = (string)prop.GetValue(message,null);
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(propValue) && ...;
            }
            return false;
        };

    }
```

Comment: And what does the body of FilterData look like?

Comment: To do this properly, after checking that `prop` is not `null`, you should also make sure that `prop.CanRead` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and dirty approach could be an `enum` plus some kind of magic:

```
public enum FilterTarget { Body, AnyOtherProp };
public Expression<Func<Message, bool>> FilterData(FilterTarget filterTarget)
{
    string toBeFiltered = string.Empty;

    switch(filterTarget)
    {
        case FilterTarget.Body : 
        { toBeFiltered = message.Body; } break;
        case FilterTarget.AnyOtherProp : 
        { toBeFiltered = message.AnyOtherProp; } break;
        default: 
        { 
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("Unsupported property {0}", filterTarget.ToString()
            ); 
        } 
    }

    switch (this.operatorEnum)
    {
        case FilterParameterOperatorEnum.EqualTo:
            return message => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(toBeFiltered) &&
                              toBeFiltered.Equals(this.value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

      /* CUT: other cases are similar */
    }
}
```

You can make the `FilterData` method even more fancy letting it  accept a `params FilterTarget[]` thus gaining multi-filtering capabilities (off the top of my head, code not included).

Usage:

```
var aFilterDataResult = FilterData(FilterTarget.Body);    
var anotherFilterDataResult = FilterData(FilterTarget.AnyOtherProp);
...
```